# UITableView loads with cells in the middle of the TableView. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

**Context**

- Building for iOS 7
- Two UITableViews on a viewcontroller
- Using constraints so tableview resize like I'd like for between 3.5inch and 4inch screen sizes.

[image]

**What I've tried**

- Read UITableView documentation
- Search stackoverflow
- tried this code: `[self.bottomTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];`

**Result**

- The content in the bottom tableView loads in the middle of the tableview. I can scroll those cells upwards towards the top of the table view, but they "snap" back to the middle. How do I avoid this?

**Update**

This is how the tableview looks on load. The green background shows all the white space that left on the top half of the bottom table view.

[image]

This is the code:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.topTableView) {
        return [self.array count];
    }
    else{
        return [self.array count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.topTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"60";

        return cell;
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"60";

        return cell;
    }

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Comment: can you show actual images with cell & also your tableview code?

Comment: Please, can you show the code where you ser up the tableView (frame, delegates...)? Thank you?

Comment: I dont see problems with the code you provide, but I dont see how you set up the tableview in code or interfacebuilder. Nor can I see whats happen during runtime. Mind zipping the project and share it, so we can look closer?

Comment: @HelgeBecker here you go: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/529504/Example.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code. It seems to be a bug with Xcode and iOS 7 unless I missed something in the WWDC documentation.

He applies the height of the navbar to the first element in the subviews array. It doesn't matter if the element is actually under the bar, he just blindly applies it. You can change the order in the storyboard, lets say you move the bottom tableview to the top, then the bottom view has the problem.

I see two options.
If you disable "Under Top Bars" on the ViewController everything is fine. Or you move the UILabel to the top. There is nothing he can adjust with the static label. Maybe Xcode 5.0.1 that was released with the Maverics GM will fix that. Still downloading that one. Will try as soon DL is done.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nope, same with XCode 5.0.1. He seems to do this the topmost element if the class inherit UIView. Oh well, Bugreport.

Comment: How do you "disable "Under Top Bars"?

Comment: Programatically (UIViewController property in iOS7) or in the storyboard. Let me add a picture where.

Comment: Have you logged this with Apple already? I'd like if you haven't.

Comment: Also when I switch off the "under top bars" property I get this weird colour transition behind he nav bar.

Comment: No, didnt have it yet. Feel free to. :)

Comment: Any ideas on how to avoid the color transition occurring when I switch off "extend edges - under top bars"

Comment: In which method are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry new file - I'm just using a push segue to transition between view controllers embedded in a nav controller.